# Integrate Laravel Dusk Testing Result in TestRail

Tags: integration-testing, laravel-dusk, testrail

I just want to raise here if does anyone already did to integrate Laravel Dusk Testing in TestRail, a test management tool?

I did try searching through website and I cannot find the step-by-step guide.I hope anyone can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Laravel, but quick googling shows that you can generate JUnit XML report by using `php artisan test --log-junit junit.xml`.
Once you have XML report, you can use the [Railflow](https://railflow.io) for uploading it into TestRail.
Please see the [docs](https://docs.railflow.io/docs/railflow-for-testrail/railflow-cli/cli-reference) for more details.

Railflow is a commercial tool but has free support for JUnit XML format.

Disclaimer: I'm developing Railflow.